# Changing attributes and EP

Tags: besm, besm-3e

I've worked out a houserule, but is there any official ruling on what happens in BESM 3rd edition to your EP or HP total when your stats change? For example, if you drain someone's Mind score and boost your own, your EP cap raises; does your current EP total rise to meet it? If you have your Mind score drained, your EP cap lowers; does your current EP total lower as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is mentioned in the Alternate Form attribute, p19 (emphasis mine):

> Whenever characters who have lost Health Points change form, **their
>   present totals are always adjusted proportionately**: multiply current
>   Health Points by their latest form’s base Health Points and then
>   divide by their prior form’s base Health Points (Current Health x New
>   Form Base Health ÷ Old Form Base Health). **The same applies to Energy
>   Points.** This means that if a human with 60 Health Points was reduced
>   to 30 Health Points after taking various injuries, and then changed
>   into a cat with a base 20 Health Points, the cat-form’s current Health
>   Points would be 30 x 20 ÷ by 60 = 10 Health Points. Suppose the
>   shapeshifter then suffered further injuries whilst a cat, dropping to
>   2 Health Points; after turning back to human form, he or she would
>   become a human with 2 x 60 ÷ 20 = 6 Health Points.

While it is in the Alternate Form attribute, this would logically apply to anything that changes your stats.

Comment: Oh, of course! Under Alternate Form, rather than under EP or HP or ability drain or anywhere useful like that. I should have guessed. Thanks :)

Comment: @Yamikuronue To be fair, the book is not known for its clarity and organization... And I found that part entirely by accident :p